# Encountering "Maximum update depth exceeded" whilst using react-auth-kit to make private routes

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, jwt

I am trying to implement an authentication system for a React website with the react-auth-kit library. So far, I've been able to get the Sign In process to work with successful API calls. The issue emerged when I tried to create a private route using "RequireAuth", which resulted in the website throwing an error saying "Maximum update depth exceeded", and it has never occurred before, even with useEffect hooks on other pages. I concretely followed the documentation on React Auth Kit's website, and it was of no use as well.
[The error it threw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJgX3.png)

When I successfully login using the login page, the website runs normally and allows me to enter Upload, but when it's not, I get the abovementioned error. Another side effect of this is that although it throws such error, it still lets me browse the page after it kicked me to Login, and even though the error is there, the website still works after I just close off the error.

I tried looking up some useful information on Youtube, Google, and it led me to StackOverflow, whereby I couldn't find any questions related to my problems. I've never encountered this issue before, and the code appeared too simplistic for me to expend time to make it work.

This is App's code in which I implemented multiple directories using react router dom

```
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider, RequireAuth } from 'react-auth-kit';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import About from './Pages/About';
import Articles from './Pages/Articles';
import Upload from './Pages/Upload';
import Blog from './Pages/Blog';
import IRScholarJournal from './Pages/Journal';
import SignUp from './Authentication/Signup';
import Login from './Authentication/Login';
import './App.css';

function App(){
    return(
    <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' index element={<Home/>} ></Route>
                <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} ></Route>
                <Route path='/articles' element={<Articles/>} ></Route>
                <Route path='/upload' element={
                <RequireAuth loginPath={'/login'}>
                    <Upload/>
                </RequireAuth>
                }>
                </Route>
                <Route path='/blog' element={<Blog/>} ></Route>
                <Route path='/journal' element={<IRScholarJournal/>} ></Route>
                <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp/>} ></Route>
                <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} ></Route>
            </Routes>
            <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>        
    </div>);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue in the `RequireAuth` component. I checked the github issues and didn't see any related issues. Perhaps you should file a new issue there.